# dragablz TabablzControl disable tab

Tags: c#, wpf, tabitem

Hello I am working with dragablz:TabablzControl and I need disable a tab but I can't.

This is my code:

```
<dragablz:TabablzControl
        FixedHeaderCount="4"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        BorderThickness="0"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTab}">
        <TabItem Header="{Resx ApplicationView_mnuStatus}" IsEnabled="false"  Visibility="Hidden" >
            <views:StatusView>
                <views:StatusView.DataContext>
                    <viewmodels:StatusViewModel />
                </views:StatusView.DataContext>
            </views:StatusView>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="{Resx ApplicationView_mnuServers}" IsEnabled="false"  Visibility="Hidden" >
            <views:ServersMainView>
                <views:ServersMainView.DataContext>
                    <viewmodels:ServersMainViewModel />
                </views:ServersMainView.DataContext>
            </views:ServersMainView>
        </TabItem>
    </dragablz:TabablzControl>
```

Visibility = "hidden" doesn't work
isEnabled = "false" does't work

Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dragablz doesn't support disabling of a tab.

Why?  Because it doesn't make too much sense in a scenario where other tabs could be dragged into another window, leaving your disabled tab exposed.

You should either:

- Disable the content of your tab.
- Remove the tab you want to hide.

Comment: How to Remove the tab you want to hide?
tab1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; not work in Window_Loaded Event and shows always tab1 tabItem.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply remove tab item in code behind :

```
TabablzControl1.Items.Remove(tabitem1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
List<object> ListTabItem = new List<object>();
bool band = false;
foreach (object item in tabcontent.Items){
    if (band == false){
        band = true;
        continue;
    }
    ListTabItem.Add(item);
}

private void VisibleTabs(string cad){
    foreach (object item in ListTabItem){
        tabcontent.Items.Add(item);
    }
}

private void HideTabs(string cad){
    foreach (object item in ListTabItem)
    {
        tabcontent.Items.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).